# Added custom styles(style_formats) to tinyMCE. Classes are appended and not replaced as intended

Tags: tinymce

Followed several tutorials and have added custom classes in the formats section of the tinyMCE. The classes used are being appended and not replaced as I had intended. Is there a way to have them overwrite the existing style if there is one instead of adding to the class tag?

My use case is this: The user select a piece of text and select a class from the formats dropdown I have added. They dont like the color of the link and decide to change it by going back up to the formats tab and selecting a different value. Behind the scenes, TinyMCe replaces the class. I realize I could use the styles key in the json array, but that would produce inline-styles, which I'd like to avoid.

Thanks!

[image: please check this image regarding question]

[image: please check this image with the appended class problem]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `exact: true` for your style?

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#exact

Answer (score -2):

fixed the issue by using inline css rather than using the classes